# Plotly.js define shape of data

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm pulling data from an API that comes back in the following format:

```
[{
  "metadata": {"colName": "nameOfCol"},
  "value": valueForCol // string or number or whatever
},
...]
```

But according to Plotly's website, they want two simple arrays of labels and columns:

```
var data = [{
  values: [19, 26, 55],
  labels: ['Residential', 'Non-Residential', 'Utility'],
  type: 'pie'
}];
```

or:

```
var data = [{
  x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
  y: [20, 14, 23],
  type: 'bar'
}];
```

Now there's quite a big dataset coming back, so I'd prefer to not have to loop through the whole set and extract the labels and values from everything.  Is there a nice way to tell Plotly to loop through my data and find the labels and values?

I don't know what this would look like, maybe something like:

```
var data = [{
  source: myData,
  labels: "metadata.colName",
  values: "value",
  type: "pie"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no, there is no feature in Plotly.js for this, you'll unfortunately have to loop through and extract.

Comment: Is there a long answer too?

Comment: Not as far as I know, and I sit next to one of the core devs :)